# One to one relationship. Is Id column needed for both table?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, data-structures

Let's consider the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo_1] (
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [UserId] INT,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserId FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo_2] (
    [UserId] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserId FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] (Id)
);
```

What are the procs and cons of using  `FOREIGN KEY` for `UserInfo_1 and UserInfo_2` tables? Also in terms of ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there would be a con for using Foreign Keys on any form of tables. In fact, I make sure to have a primary key on all tables I use, especially on temps and variable tables since I know I will be joining and filtering with them.

Now your first table `User` and `UserInfo_1` is a one to many relationship. Meaning a single User can have many different `UserInfo_1` associated with it.

the second one of `User` and `UserInfo_2` is a one to one relationship. In which a single `User` can only ever have one `UserInfo_2` associated with it.

In terms of performance, since they are Indexed they would perform relatively the same, depending upon your filtering and what plan was cached in the query plan. though you may not entirely run into issues with cached query plans as EF utilizes ad-hock statements, though EF does run up the cached plan memory and that is typically recommended to be disabled when using EF.

**One-to-One**

I am a fan of one to one relationship, especially in a Domain Driven Design aspect, and when implemented correctly. If each of your rows for `User` is going to require information from `UserInfo_2`, then I would theoretically keep them on the `User` table. Now if you know you will not be querying that information much or not all `Users` will require the columns on that table, or if your main table is fairly large I would keep it as a one to one relationship.

I personally like to use System Versioning. I have tables which contain certain columns which typically update and columns which almost never update. Those that I know update on a daily/weekly bases I have them congregated on a one to one relationship to the main table that should almost never update. But each business needs and scenario is different. Not any one design fits all situations.

**Benefits of Indexing**

When you create a Foreign Key, you are creating an Index in the database. This will allow for you to perform faster queries. The SQL optimizer will utilize the Index to better find what you are looking for. Without the index, your query plan will turn into a table scan, which is a row by row search. When doing a row by row search, you can seriously slow your system down as your table grows.

Should you choose to create your tables without an Index, or in this case a Foreign Key index, you might find issues with the ORM aspect. When you query your database from EF, you will call your DbSet. If you had proper Foreign Key connections with your two tables, EF can utilize the `.Include` to join the two tables searching for what you need. Otherwise you would be forced to utilize two queries into the database for both tables.

In a project I worked on one time, a developer did that. He did not properly attach a Foreign Key connection between two objects and then didn't understand why EF would not properly return his values when he used the `.Include` and wasn't very fast. He thought it was EF's fault and had to do two queries to obtain the information he needed.

Comment: Well there are performance and space disadvantages formatting additional constraints or indexes. Not to mention the additional need for managing keys (and possibly reconciliation if records come from different sources).

Comment: That all depends upon the business needs and relationships.  I would say the performance and space disadvantages do not outweigh the benefits of indexing, when indexing properly. In a relational database all tables should have a key, whether that be a composite key or not deoends upon the relationship. 

When a person just adds indexes and doest take into account proper needs, such as fill-factors, etc. Yes you can find yourself in a head-ach of a clean up. And the issues of managing keys and reconciliation is a part of the a product life-cycle, there is no getting around that.

Answer (score 1):

Well User > UserInfo_1 is a one-to-many relationship, as UserInfo_1.UserID is not a key.  And EF 6 doesn't support alternate keys.  EF Core does, so you could make it a key.

But the simplest design is always to collapse 1-1 relationships into a single table.  In EF Core you can still have a main Entity Type and one or more separate [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities).  But on the database it's typically better to have them in a single table.

The second-simplest is to have have both tables have the same key columns.

Comment: What if UserId in UserInfo_1 table will be unique? In this case, it will be a real one to one

Comment: About `collapse 1-1 relationships into a single table`: In this case, we will need to read more pages from disk in order to read data, even if we need just Select columns from User table

Comment: That depends on the indexes on the table.  If an index, or an index with included columns has the target columns, the main table wouldn't be read.  And the flip-side is the need to process a JOIN when accessing any of the additional columns.  Basic best-practice is not to adjust your logical data model for imagined performance concerns.  Use the simplest correct logical model, and worry about performance later when it can be tested and measured, and address it primarily with physical data structures (indexes, etc).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - "Use the simplest correct logical model, and worry about performance later when it can be tested and measured" - that should be the standard answer to anyone who is designing in advance for performance. :)

Comment: The 2 reasons I have found 1-1 relationships to be useful are 1) When only a small number of records in table1 require the additional information in table2. 2) When there are so many indexes on table1 that performance is impacted, which can happen for a core table in a system.